# How to get email address of a user using Google Oauth .NET library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I would like to get the email address of a user after successful sign-in. Google Plus APIs will be depreciated by Google. Any other way to access just email address of the user? Using the below code, I'll have access access token and id_token of the user.

```
UserCredential credential =
                GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                    , scopes
                    , userName
                    , CancellationToken.None
                    , new FileDataStore(fileDataStorePath)).Result;
```

Update: The following code worked.

```
           var gmailService = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "App name"
            });

            var gmailProfile = gmailService.Users.GetProfile("me").Execute();
            string EmailAddress = gmailProfile.EmailAddress;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have include the "email" scope as part of your scopes.

create a service object.

```
var service = new PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Peopleservice Oauth2 Authentication Sample"
    });
```

Then make a request to the people api.

```
var results = service.People.Get("person/me").ExecuteAsync();
```